# mod_rewrite replace all instances of ampersand with %26 for later

Tags: php, mod-rewrite, urlencode, ampersand

I want to simply not use ampersand in my URL so I can pass ampersands further down into my system when a file is requested. The problem is Apache deals with it differently. I don't know how

I already rewrite the requested file to index.php?url=$1 so I can see what it was, but if it has an ampersand in there, it can't continue past it!

how can I escape the ampersand or turn it into it's hex equal (%26)?

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper way to escape ampersand in a query string modified by `mod_rewrite` is

```
%2526
```

if it's being handled by php.

When apache rewrites it, it's turned from `%2526` to `%26` which php then converts into `&` and stores in the query variable.

Using the `B` rewrite rule works too, but then all plus signs in the parameter remain plus signs in php.

The real world example that I had to face:

```
/group/Simon+%26+Garfunkel
```

With `B` it rewrites to

```
group.php?group=Simon+%26+Garfunkel
```

and in php you get

```
$group="Simon+&+Garfunkel";
```

when you wanted

```
$group="Simon & Garfunkel"
```

With B you need

```
/group/Simon%20%26%20Garfunkel
```

which works fine.

without `B` you get

```
group.php?group=Simon%20&%20Garfunkel
```

and you end up with

```
$group="Simon ";
```

because the `&` divides query strings.

But if you double escape

```
/group/Simon+%2526+Garfunkel
```

it rewrites to

```
group.php?group=Simon%20%26%20Garfunkel
```

and you end up with

```
$group="Simon & Garfunkel";
```

like expected.

If the url is NOT parsed by `mod_rewrite` into a "clean url", then we can use `%26` just fine.

Answer (score 4):

1st make sure the url's you're building have escaped the & symbol to %26 so it's not an ampersand when it gets to your server. then in your rewrite rule add the B tag so it won't convert it back to the &:

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [B,QSA,L]

This B tag saved my butt after 2 days of trying different rewrite rules.

Answer (score 1):

Add

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)\&(.*)$ $1\%26$2
```

To your rewrite rules.

Comment: hmm, this seems to break the !-f condition from above and now all external files arn't working on the server

Comment: Where did you put the RewriteRule line?

Answer (score 0):

Try putting this rule above yours:

```
RewriteRule ^([^&]*)&(.*) $1\%26$2 [N]
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition if you want to send back to the browser a redirect with the ampersand in the URL you can add the [NE] flag to the end of the RewriteRule.

```
RewriteRule ^/(.*) /index.php?p=yourpage_\%26_something_else [NC,NE,R=301,L]
```